# How to run a script everywhere in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script HOST_AVAI.sh in `/home/campus27/zwang10/bin`. And in my .bashrc, I add `export PATH=$PATH:/home/zwang10/bin/HOST_AVAI.sh`. But after I type `HOST_AVAI.sh`, it shows `HOST_AVAI.sh: Command not found.`.
Can someone help me here?

**ADDED**

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/tcsh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path should be `PATH=$PATH:/home/zwang10/bin` and add this in `.bash_profile`. After this run the script with following command :

```
$ . .bash_profile
```

Make sure your `HOST_AVAI.sh` must have the execute permission.

```
$ cd  /home/zwang10/bin
$ chmod +x HOST_AVAI.sh
```

now run this command from anywhere.

Comment: After I type `. .bash_profile`, it shows `/usr/local/bin/.: Permission denied.`

Comment: if it is not working then close the window and login again your profile will be activated. then you can use your command

Comment: I logout and then login, and type `HOST_AVAI.sh`. it shows `HOST_AVAI.sh: Command not found.`Previously, I mess the .bash_profile file.And now there is only one line in this file that is `PATH=$PATH:/home/zwang10/bin`. Does this matter?

Comment: Finally, i figure it out, there is a file called '.cshrc' .after i added path there. it works now.